# Calculate driving distance between origin and destination using longitude and latitude natively in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, r, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to calculate **driving** distance between two points writing SQL in Google BigQuery. I understand there is a method to calculate linear distance or "bird" miles using the following function: `ROUND(ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(C.LONGITUDE, C.LATITUDE), ST_GEOGPOINT(B.LNG_NBR, B.LAT_NBR))/1609.34,2) AS LINEAR_DIST_MILES`

However, I am interested in driving distance instead of a linear distance. Is there a way to do this natively in Google BigQuery without needing to hit a Google Map API? I've also explored some solutions in R but that requires a Google Maps API key.

Comment: You must need the road data to perform that computation. BigQuery has geo function to figure out the distance between 2 points, but without the road layer. BigQuery Google Earth data could help. But the easiest way is to use the Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

You would need two parts

1. good roads datasets
2. routing algorithms

BigQuery public datasets includes OpenStreetMaps, which is a reasonable dataset of roads (and other types of information) in most areas. There is also TIGER (`bigquery-public-data.geo_us_roads`) dataset which is US-specific.

Carto provides a sets of UDFs that can be used for routing. They've published an article how to connect things together:

https://carto.com/blog/how-to-do-route-optimization-at-scale-with-carto-bigquery/