# Bigquery driving distance using coordenades with a dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the driving distance from a fixed point to points in a table that i have using longitude and latitude with bigquery. I have some experience with sql, but not to this degree and this my first time using bigquery so im a bit confuse.
Thanks for your time.

I was trying to write the coordinates of a specific point in the query, for it to calculate that driving distance and to get a table with that information, but a this point I have no idea what im doing.

Comment: Distance between two points: `ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(start_lng, start_lat), ST_GEOGPOINT(end_lng, end_lat))`

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/73626644/5221944

Comment: I'm not sure it is duplicate. This question asks about **driving** distance, while ST_DISTANCE is "fling" distance - directly from A to B, regardless of the road network. Ignacio, could you clarify?